# Removing an object from specific lighting

Tags: light

I have got a problem with my lighting. The overall lighting for the scene is what I want it to be, however there is a specific object (my logo) that I would like to be light in a different fashion to make it look more metallic/shiny.

The way the lighting is set up for the rest of the scene, means that the logo is getting hit by the light almost directly from the front, this causes it to look less 3D and much less metallic.

I'm looking for a way to prevent the object from being hit by the main scene lighting, so that it can have it's own individual light.

The lone object with it's personal lighting:

[image: LogoWithNiceLighting]

The scene with the object no longer having personal lighting:

[image: LogoWithBadSceneLighting]

I'd like the logo to look like it does in the first picture.

Thank you

Comment: put your logo and it's separate lights on a different layer see: https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/layers.html?highlight=layer

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33897/can-someone-explain-the-layer-system

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: The most simple or common way would be to use multiple files instead of one. 1 file with the background, one with the logo. Render out each animation as image sequence. Then perhaps in a third file load the two image sequences and render out the combined result.

Method 2: If you're using Blender Internal Render, another way would be to limit lighting for your materials to a specific lamp group:
[image]

Method 3: You could put your special object and its special lighting to a different layer as everything else. Then set the render layer not to render the layer for the special object. Create a new render layer and set it to only render the layer for the special object. Enable Compositing, and use nodes for compositing. Add another render layer node. Set it to the render layer for your special object. Combine the two render layer color outputs with a color mix node. Make sure you're rendering with transparency and that the color mix node is set to use the transparency of the second input. (This method is basically method one, but all-in-one)