# Difference in render preview and actual render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, scene, render-layers, layers

In my preview, the scene renders perfectly. In the actual render, only the shading of the objects is visible on the ground.

I know i've moved some things around between layers to clean up my scene, but i'm in the dark on what causes this. Anyone any idea? I'm using the official 2.79 build.

[image]

Comment: Man, just minutes after posting i found the problem. My Renderlayer wasn't set up correctly. Just selecting the layers on the bottom of the 3d-viewport isn't enough. The Renderlayer settings ultimately decided what gets rendered and what not.

Comment: That's what render layer does. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33897/can-someone-explain-the-layer-system