# how can i see all layers when i render animation?

Tags: animation

I have made my different object in different layers & trying to animate like object appear for few sec & again disappears & than other layers object appears & disappears.
but when i render it in object mode it show me same as i want. But when i animate it just show 1st layers & other layers object doesn't appears. how can i see all layers when i do render animation?

[image]

this is the image when i do render animation or render image

Comment: Suggest animating the objects `hide_render` property (Camera icon on outliner) Properties Renderlayers shows the layers that are rendered, this property cannot be animated.

Comment: The information you posted is not enough to understand your scene and settings. Please **read carefully** through the answers on these pages: [Possible causes for blank output on rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632) and [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490). Try the proposed solutions. If you still can't solve your problem, then use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) to add more information, and add images that illustrate how you set up your project and settings.

Comment: Maybe related: [Can someone explain the layer system?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33897/can-someone-explain-the-layer-system)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding, I believe you want the Render Layers feature. It's in the second tab of the Properties editor

you can choose which layers are visible in the final render using the boxes on the left-hand side:
[image: Properties editor with render layers]
[image: Only Cube layer selected]
Without sphere's layer selected
[image: Both layers selected]
With sphere's layer selected as well

that's the simplest use for it at least, there's a lot of useful things other than that as well