# How can I render all layers?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-layers, scene

If I put each character on a different layer, can I still render my animation with the characters in the scene?

Comment: just shift-click the layers to include in the render?

Comment: related:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33897/can-someone-explain-the-layer-system