# Renders coming out completely white

Tags: rendering, animation

I've been trying to learn some basic blender stuff and I'm trying to render a small animation out to After Effects for compositing.

However, when I try and render the animation, the image comes out completely white
[image]

This is what it looks like if I just render the one frame
[image]

and this is what it looks like in the viewport
[image]
If its fine with just a single frame render, why isn't it working for the animation?

Here's the .blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AzEwQUvbfivx6lFPLStplxBoxI34YmFB

Comment: can you share the .blend file?

Comment: Most likely your object is in a layer that is not part of your render layers. Please read the following link carefull: [render result is blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) specially the part that reads: **Objects or camera are in different render layers**. Go through the many possible solutions in the link and report back

Comment: Maybe related: [Can someone explain the layer system?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33897/can-someone-explain-the-layer-system)

Comment: the thing is I can see it rendering out the correct thing for the animation but the file in the folder on my computer is completely white.
How can I share the .blend file?

Comment: Here's the .blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AzEwQUvbfivx6lFPLStplxBoxI34YmFB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I needed to uncheck Compositing under the post-processing tab. This gave me the result I was looking for.

That's solved the headache I've spent the last four days trying to solve...

Answer (score -1):

Or, you could turn compositing back on, and go into the compositor and make sure everything is connected that should be.

Comment: "Make sure everything is connected that should be." isn't very helpful. It's more like "Do it right!" without explaining what right is. Please consider expanding your answer with at least some explanation.